# Symfony - prod server : polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: symfony, production, apache2.4

I'm trying to deploy my symfony 6.2 project on my prod server with apache2.

My prod server already have older symfony projects, so i use ondrej php and installed php8.2 and mods.

```bash
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
```

Deploy git project and run composer:install.

Here is my project.conf :

```bash
<virtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin admin@mysterty.com
  ServerName project.mysterty.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/project/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/project/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                Require all granted

                <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                        Options -MultiViews
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        Options +FollowSymlinks

                        RewriteEngine On
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
                        RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

                        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
                        RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

                        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
                        RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                        RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
                        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
                                # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
                                # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
                                # and the generated links can still be used.
                                RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
                                # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
                        </IfModule>
                </IfModule>

  </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      # For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the error message :

```bash
[Tue Apr 11 11:49:40.112857 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3184524] [client 194.38.23.179:63349] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/project/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 78; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/project/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:78\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(61): composerRequiree6ce3b729b7a527d4ebd0a97b86ba908()\n#1 /var/www/project/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInite6ce3b729b7a527d4ebd0a97b86ba908::getLoader()\n#2 /var/www/project/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('...')\n#3 /var/www/project/public/index.php(5): require_once('...')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 78'
```

I assume the project works on my local server (ubuntu/apache2) with similar config.

Comment: your server does not have right permissions : see https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#2-use-the-same-user-for-the-cli-and-the-web-server

Comment: It's not that.

This is for fixing `project/var` permissions, and it doesn't fix my problem, even using acl or umask.